# Ubuntu doesn't boot for an unknown reason

Tags: 20.04, freeze

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. It was freezing once every day, however a restart was a good solution for it, and then it worked fine. Last time I was trying to open the Settings app, but there was no response at all. I restarted it and now it doesn't boot at all.

Ubuntu boots to a black screen with this boot message:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 374354/31227904 files, 13694991/124895488 blocks
[    3.735374] usb usb1-port14: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[    4.605961] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Not really. I had a working version, but no idea why it crashed, and if it is related to the non-responsive settings.

Comment: What is the video card? Did you install drivers?

Comment: I really don't know. It is a new laptop :( But I hadn't install any drivers, I only installed fresh version of ubuntu and was working fine for the last week.

Comment: Quite often this type of problem usually related to hardware.  Giving computer make and model with CPU and GPU, can narrow down what the problem is.

Comment: Latitude 15 5501 Laptop. Core i7-9850H Processor (6 Core, 12MB Cache, 2.6 GHz, 4.6GHz Turbo, 35W vPro).
This helps somehow?

Comment: I diagnose this freezing problem as possibly being due to faulty RAM. Usually if there is a problem with faulty RAM a message about RAM will appear on the screen when the computer is booting.